# data memory usage of ndb cluster with disk storage?

Tags: mysql

I want to know exact usage of "data memory" of ndb cluster with disk storage.

I already know indexes and some(first 256 bytes) data of text and blob type is saved on data memory.

I want to know if data memory works as LRU cache? or read cache of disk storage data ?

Any comments or links will be appreciate.

Jinho